# Replace LaTeX formulas in HTML markup with IMG tags linked to generated SVG images

Tags: html, svg, latex, converters, mathjax

I have an XML file witch in some nodes contains HTML markup. I want to be able to use LaTeX formulas there. I'm trying to find a way to generate another XML file with those formulas replaced with *<img src="...">* tags, and produce corresponding svg images. Is there a tool for that, or is the task to specific and I need to write it myself? I was hoping that there is something that I could tweak a little to get it to work like that.

Example is below:

**Input file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <snippet>
    In mathematics, <b>Euler's identity</b> is the equality $e^{i\pi}+1=0$.
    </snippet> 
    <snippet>
     <a href="einstain.html">Albert Einstein</a>'s famous formula:
     $$E=mc^2$$
    </snippet>
</root>
```

**Output files:**

*f1.svg*

*f2.svg*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <snippet>
    In mathematics, <b>Euler's identity</b> is the equality <img src="f1.svg" />.
    </snippet> 
    <snippet>
     <a href="einstain.html">Albert Einstein</a>'s famous formula:

     <img src="f2.svg" />

    </snippet>
</root>
```

I was looking into *mathjax-node* and *mathjax-node-cli* and found the tool *tex2svg* witch takes a TeX string and produces a single image. Seems like a part of what I need, but there's still a lot to do.

Comment: You may be able to use Peter Krautzberger's [mathjax-node-page](https://github.com/pkra/mathjax-node-page) tool that builds on `mathjax-node` to handle a page at once.  Note, however, that in-line formulas will probably need to have `vertical-align` set properly to place the baseline correctly.  I'm not sure if Peter's tool does that.